# How to get right format depending on type of content with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

**Intro**

I am currently working on a platform with multiple post formats, like text, links, location etc. Each type of content has his own markup. So text has a HTML markup for showing an title and text, location has a markup for showing a map e.d

*Data is stored in a JSON object.*

**The code / problem**

What I have now is, that Ajax will loop through my content and fill in the blanks. This is working fine, but the problem is that the data will be always appended to the format-text.html markup. This is not what I want, I would like to have a code that checks what type of object it is and depending on the type of post it will choose the right markup file.

Each markup is stored in a separate HTML file. Like `format-text.html` and `format-location.html`.

**Code:**

```
// Declare variables
var root = this; // This in this function

    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/videoData.js',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {

            $.get('directives/format-text.html', function(response){
                console.log('succes');
            })

            .done(function (response) {
                // console.dir(response);
                var raw_model = response;
                var loadOnScroll = false;

                // Start loop
                var modelParts = data.content.length;
                var modelCount = 0;

                function loadData() {

                    for (var i = 0; i < modelParts; i++) {

                        // if (data.content[i].type == 'normal') {

                            model = $(raw_model);
                            var dataID = data.content[modelCount].timeTrigger;
                            var dataIndex = modelCount;

                            model.attr('data-id', dataID);
                            model.attr('data-index', dataIndex);

                            // console.log(data.content[modelCount].type);
                            model.find('.format').addClass(' ' + data.content[modelCount].type);
                            model.find('h4').html(data.content[modelCount].subtitle);
                            model.find('h3').html(data.content[modelCount].title).wrap('<a href="#' + '' + '"></a>');
                            model.find('p').html(data.content[modelCount].text);
                            model.find('.contentHolder').append('<a href="' + data.content[modelCount].readmore + '" target="_blank" class="button primary">Read more</a>');

                            $(model).insertBefore('.featured .footer');

                        // }

                        modelCount++;
                        console.log(modelCount);
                    }

                    $('body').removeClass('loading'); 

                } loadData();

            })

            .fail(function (response) {
                console.dir(response); 
            });

        },

        error: function(data) { 
            console.log(data);
            console.log('Houston, we have a problem!');
        }


    });
```

**JSON:**

```
{
        "title":    "Hello World JSON",
        "content":  [
            {
                "type" :        "location",
                "timeTrigger":  25,
                "title":        "London",
                "google":       "https://www.google.nl/maps/place/Londen,+Verenigd+Koninkrijk/@51.5340878,-0.0978221,12z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x47d8a00baf21de75:0x52963a5addd52a99"
            },{
                "type":         "text",
                "timeTrigger":  34,
                "title":        "Hello World!",
                "subtitle":     "Format",
                "picture" :     "images/content/helloworld.png",
                "text":         "Lorem ipsum dolar ismat.",
                "readmore":     "https://www.google.nl/"
            },{
                "type":         "text",
                "timeTrigger":  34,
                "title":        "Hello World 2!",
                "subtitle":     "Format",
                "picture" :     "images/content/helloworld_two.png",
                "text":         "Lorem ipsum dolar ismat 2.",
                "readmore":     "https://www.google.nl/"
            },{
                "type" :        "location",
                "timeTrigger":  25,
                "title":        "London",
                "google":       "https://www.google.nl/maps/place/Londen,+Verenigd+Koninkrijk/@51.5340878,-0.0978221,12z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x47d8a00baf21de75:0x52963a5addd52a99"
            },{
                "type":         "text",
                "timeTrigger":  34,
                "title":        "Hello World!",
                "subtitle":     "Format",
                "picture" :     "images/content/helloworld.png",
                "text":         "Lorem ipsum dolar ismat.",
                "readmore":     "https://www.google.nl/"
            }
    ]
}
```

**HTML markup:**

```
<div class="article text">
    <span class="alignRight format"></span>

    <div class="contentHolder">
        <h4></h4>
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
    </div><!-- End div.contentHolder -->

</div><!-- End div.article text -->
```

**Steps:**

I think the code should work like below procedure:
1. Get JSON data
2. Loop through the content
3. Check the type of object
4. If is text, use format-text.html
5. If is location, use format-location.html

By generating the real html output, I would like to add index that is not depending on the type of post. So if the order is - text, text, location, text - the index should be 0, 1, 2, 3

I look out for some advice. If there are any questions let me know.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you put this together in a jsfiddle please :) or are you getting JSON data locally?

Comment: Everything is locally stored...